# Understanding Euler's Identity

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I would like to understand one specific moment in Euler's Identity, namely

$$e^{j\theta}=\cos(\theta)+j\sin(\theta)$$

where $j=\sqrt{-1}$. We also know that

$$e^{j2(\pi)}=\cos(2\pi)+j\sin(2\pi)$$

but  $\sin(2\pi)=0$  and  $\cos(2\pi)=1$, and $1=e^{0}$, so we get that  $e^{j2(\pi)}=e^{0}$.

But we get that $j2\pi=0$ which means that $j=0$, but on the other hand $j=\sqrt{-1}$. I want to ask one question: why is it allowed to use such symbols in identity, which finally may cause some strange equality?

Comment: $\exp(a) = \exp(b)$ does not imply $a=b$. Check your definition of $\exp(a)$ and note, that potential rules (is this the correct english word for it?) are not valid for complex numbers in general.

Comment: Why do you use $j$ for $i$?

Comment: @TMM it's quite usual in electrical engineering fo example

Comment: It is used in electrical engineering, although since $j$ is also used (current densities), it is not clear to me why the switch was made.

Comment: Exponential functions of a REAL number are one-to-one.  Exponential functinos of a complex number are not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mistake is that $\exp: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is no longer a bijection. Thus
$$e^{2\pi i} = e^{0} \not\Rightarrow 2\pi i = 0$$
In general
$$\exp(z) = \exp(z+2\pi i) \qquad \forall\ z\in\mathbb C$$
because of the periodicity of $\sin$ and $\cos$ and the definition
$$\exp(z) = \underbrace{\exp(\Re z)}_{\exp: \mathbb R\to\mathbb R} \cdot (\cos(\Im z) + i\sin(\Im z))$$

Comment: because of rotation principle right?

Comment: However you may call it:
$$\exp(z) = \exp(\Re z) (\cos(\Im z) + i\sin(\Im z))$$

Comment: thanks very much for answer,happy new year

Comment: @datodatuashvili Perhaps, but I would sooner say it's just unwarranted to assume that $e^x = e^y$ means $x=y$ for complex numbers just because you're used to that being true for real numbers.

Comment: @datodatuashvili Thank you, likewise :) If you have anything remaining unclear, feel free to ask away. If not, please mark the question as answered.

Comment: no no i   have  finished everything,thanks for answer

Comment: wait please for $4$ minute

Comment: @AlexR  it was  marked as answered

Answer (score 2):

You are worried that $e^{j\cdot 2\pi}=\cos(2\pi)+j\sin(2\pi)=\cos(0)+j\sin(0)=e^0$, even though $j\cdot2\pi\ne0$.
Does it also worry you that
$$\cos(2\pi)=\cos(0)$$
and
$$\sin(2\pi)=\sin(0),$$
even though $2\pi\ne0$?

Comment: yes yes right,just i was thinking about this whole  day and now i am relaxed :D

Comment: Ok, very good :)